# Dynamic Cognos screen tip and description?

Tags: cognos

Is it possible to update the screen tips and descriptions of fields in Cognos Analytics 11.0.8 dynamically? We want to have a Data Definition Catalog and use it to update Cognos. The only methods I can find are fairly manual, including BPS Meta Manager.

Comment: Define "fields".  Do you mean the tooltips for the icons that are built in, descriptions of reports, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the steps to integrate InfoSphere Business Glossary into Cognos. I haven't done it, but I've heard people say that the configuration steps can be used for other catalogs, besides the InfoSphere product.

Since the configuration is just a URL, you could point this to a web server you control. Then use the web server logs to identify what Cognos appends to the URL or posts to the URL to identify the field.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cra.doc/t_configure_business_glossary.html#Configure_Business_Glossary